# Populating a c-string array using a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c-strings

For my homework assignment I have to write a function that uses a char pointer to populate a c-string array. The overall goal of the assignment is to get familiar with dynamic memory allocation. I am not familiar with this topic so it may have something to do with that. This would be easy except the function is required to be `const`, therefore I cannot increment the pointer and set each value in the array equal to the pointer.

I've tried using a for loop however because the function is const it will not let me increment read-only values.

Here is my function so far:

```
const char* MyString::c_str() const {
    char c_str[m_size];
    c_str = *m_buffer;
    return c_str;

}
```

`m_buffer` is a char* that points to a sentence.
`m_size` is the size of the pointer.

Comment: We'd surely need to see the definition for the `MyString` class.

Comment: I guess that would help, but in the meantime, it sure looks like the OP mostly need to hear about array indexing, and.. well... dynamic allocation. (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-8a-pointer-arithmetic-and-array-indexing/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/ respectively)

Comment: I can already tell there's a problem with the local variable `c_str`, which in addition to being perhaps an unwise name due to possible confusion, is a *local variable* that's released when the function returns. You can't ever return a pointer to memory on the local stack frame.

That aside, `c_str` is an array-of-character and C++ doesn't allow assignment of a character to it.  I suppose `memcpy(c_str, m_buffer, m_size); c_str[m_size] = 0;` would do the trick, but this is still using a local array that won't stick around.

Comment: A `c_str` function of a string-like class should not normally allocate anything dynamically or populate anything. An implementation would usually consist of one line, `return m_buffer;` in your case. Since your version contains just about every possible error, I suspect your entire assignment is full of problems. Perhaps you want to ask a question or two about other parts of your code.